# FO-Dicom: How to set extended negotiations?

Tags: fo-dicom

We are trying to set `TimezoneQueryAdjustment` to true, but cannot figure out how to make it work. This is what we have tried:

1. setting it on the request

```
    request.ApplicationInfo = DicomCFindApplicationInfo.CreateForWorklistQuery(false, true);
```

2. setting it on the client:

```
    client.AdditionalExtendedNegotiations.Add(new DicomExtendedNegotiation(
                DicomUID.ModalityWorklistInformationModelFind,
                DicomCFindApplicationInfo.CreateForWorklistQuery(false, true)));
```

Unfotuantely, both do not seem to work with `dcm4chee`. Can you maybe spot the problem?